# check a given string in specific line

Tags: java

I have a very dump question.I am reading a file line by line which is ".html" file.I want to check a perticular contains exits in line or not. For this I am using String class contains method.

I am checking the follwing content in line which contain inverted comma.

```
<div class="tupBin"/>
```

My syntax is like this..

```
Str line;
line.contains()
```

What should I write in contains braces..?

Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: If you want to do a search over a string which contains quotes/inverted commas in it already, you just need to take special care with your input. 
You can "escape" special characters to tell Java to treat them as normal characters. You do this by putting a backslash before them. In fact, more than just the quotes will be a problem - so will the < and > 
Check [this link](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=96) out for more information about escaping characters. 
So to search for your string, you would write:

```
boolean didContain = line.contains("\<div class=\"tupBin\"/\>");
```

If the input is read in by a scanner or stream, most likely it will be escaped for you already.

Comment: Thanks for that ngmiceli. But if my case my file  is like this 
<html><div class="tupBin"><span><i> kailash<i></span></div>....
<html>
now I am reading it line by line.suppose I am reading first line. <div class="tupBin">.......</div>.Now I want to search this" <div class="tupBin"> ".How can I do this.. this part already contain a inverted comma.

Comment: I'm sorry, I misunderstood the question. I've never heard a quotation mark called an inverted comma before.
I'll modify my answer

Comment: yes, I got it already,And please give my qustion point please..;)

Comment: More important than asking for upvotes is being sure to mark an answer as accepted so that this question is closed.

Answer (score 1):

```
line.contains("\"")
```

http://www.javacoffeebreak.com/faq/faq0050.html

Comment: Thanks tim S. This is really helpful for me.